# What's the proper way to save a reference to an object with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

What's the difference between using std::shared_ptr with & and without in order  to save a reference to an object?

```
class A{};

class B
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<A>&obj; // or std::shared_ptr<A>obj;
public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<A>r) : obj(r) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A>a(new A());
    std::unique_ptr<B>b(new B(a));
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if using smart pointers would be better than dereferencing the object (passed as a pointer) to save obj as a normal reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making `B::obj` a reference is the same no matter what type it is. A reference is a reference is a reference, doesn't matter if it's a reference to an `int` or to a `std::shared_ptr<A>`.

And note that since you pass the `B` constructor argument by value, it will go out of scope once the constructor returns, leaving any reference to `r` invalid.

Lastly, it really doesn't make any sense to save a reference to a `std::shared_ptr`. It sometimes makes sense to *pass* a `std::shared_ptr` reference argument, but not really storing such a reference. The reference is to the `std::shared_ptr` object, not what the `std::shared_ptr` is pointing to, using a reference will not increase the internal counter, and will not use the shared ownership semantics of `std::shared_ptr`.

In other words: Don't save references to `std::shared_ptr`.